# Mark job as unstable when all tests skip

Tags: python-2.7, jenkins, junit, nose, python-unittest

I have test scenario where its possible that intermittently all tests within a test run will skip (intentionally), in this case I want Jenkins to mark the build as UNSTABLE. At the moment it marks the job as PASSED, which causes issues when we want quick visual feedback (via dashboard) as to what jobs need attention as all we see are green jobs.

Background:
Tests written in python 2.7.
Test runner used is Nose.
Test results are output using ‘—with-xunit’ flag in nose.
Its a single job that's sole purpose is to run the tests.

Hoping there is a solution as I’m yet to find an obvious one. cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a post-build Groovy script to investigate the results and mark it as unstable. Take a look at this similar question:

[Jenkins Groovy Script finding null testResultAction for a successful run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26628876/jenkins-groovy-script-finding-null-testresultaction-for-a-successful-run)

The plug-in page (which contains a lot of examples):

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin